Correctness of Python implementation of numerical difference method for Cahn-Hilliard equations
Currently I am working on trying to get the Cahn-Hilliard equation solved using finite differences. I'm unsure if I am going in the right direction with my code. I have been following section 6.1 of the following paper AUTOMATED DERIVATION OF THE ADJOINT OF HIGH-LEVEL TRANSIENT FINITE ELEMENT PROGRAMS and the code is as follows
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
Lx, Ly = 100, 50 
Nx, Ny = 128, 64  
dx = Lx / Nx 
dy = Ly / Ny  
dt = 0.01 
M = 1.0 
epsilon = 1.0 
T = 10000 

# Creates initial C for u
key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
c_0 = jax.random.uniform(key, (Nx, Ny)) * 2 - 1


def update_c(c, dt, M, epsilon):
    mu = compute_mu(c, epsilon)
    return c + dt * M * laplacian_periodic(mu, dx, dy)


def laplacian_periodic(phi, dx, dy):
    laplacian_x = (jnp.roll(phi, 1, axis=0) + jnp.roll(phi, -1, axis=0) - 2 * phi) / dx**2
    laplacian_y = (jnp.roll(phi, 1, axis=1) + jnp.roll(phi, -1, axis=1) - 2 * phi) / dy**2
    return laplacian_x + laplacian_y

def compute_mu(c, epsilon):
    return -epsilon**2 * laplacian_periodic(c, dx, dy) + c * (c**2 - 1)


checkpointed_update_c = jax.checkpoint(update_c)

def time_step(c, dt, M, epsilon, steps):
    def body_fn(c, _):
        c = checkpointed_update_phi(c, dt, M, epsilon)
        return phi, None
    c, _ = jax.lax.scan(body_fn, c, None, length=steps)
    return c

phi = time_step(c_0, dt, M, epsilon, T)

plt.imshow(phi, cmap='bwr', extent=[0, Lx, 0, Ly])
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Final Order Parameter')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()



Any help would be greatly appreciated.

No worries thanks for the correction

It seems to me like math.stackexchange is the wrong place for this question.

The computation of the chemical potential $\mu$ is not correct, as you usually want to use a double well potential. I'm not sure what yours is supposed to be.

I can see why that would be said; however, I'd like to see if Maths stack exchange can see a problem with this method of computing the cahn Hillard, which I believe is ideal for Maths stack exchange rather than computer stack exchange.

@Nuke_Gunray I don't think so. Numerical methods are in the "domain of competence" of MathSE.

Try checking the different parts of your code via the method of manufactured solutions. It would also help any potential users if you would describe in any how your code is currently performing relative to expectations. It is unreasonable to just post code and ask users to verify it is correct if you haven't made an effort to do so yourself

@whpowell96 appreciate the comment,
